# Python assignment with AND and OR

Tags: python, variable-assignment, boolean-operations

I am not much familiar with python. and I am write now looking into one code from python and it says something like this:

```
query = url.query and ('?' + url.query) or ''
```

can anyone help me understand what this means. 
I found something similar [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). but I couldn't interpret the above statement.
I am suppose to convert this line in Java.

Comment: this is bad code ...

Comment: Documentation for the `and`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is very old - and quite unreliable - syntax for a ternary if. In modern Python it should be:

```
query = '?' + url.query if url.query else ''
```

and in Java:

```
query = url.query == '' ? '' : '?' + url.query
```

Comment: but in python url.query is actually a string, so in my code I should be checking it with the null, right?

Comment: Sorry, updated. You need to compare it with the empty string.